# How to add watermark to video. i.e. both png and text

Tags: video, text, ffmpeg, command, watermark

I want to add a watermark to my video. I want to add both text and a png as watermark. I want to place text at the bottom of the image. I was able to place an  image but I am not able to place both image and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is simply, if you have the video with png watemark, now you have to put text in this new video, for example:

> base_video.mp4 with watemark png is called input_with_image.mp4

```
ffmpeg -i input_with_image.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=text='Hi Usama Shakeel':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white" -c:a copy -strict -2 output.mp4
```

solution:

> ADD PNG AND TEXT **top left side**

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=5:5,drawtext=text=:x=(w-0)/8:y=(h-4)/10:fontsize=64:fontcolor=white:thithi" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to put both png and text in the video as watermark. 
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=100:100,drawtext=text='Hello World':fontsize=64:fontcolor:white" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
with this command i could add text with the png but i could not change its placement

Comment: @UsamaShakeel i agree the solution, now you can probe the diferents sides to put png and text

Comment: @stevejobs `drawtext=text=:x` should be `drawtext=text='enter your text here':x`. Remove `:thithi`. Not sure what that is supposed to be.